# element.getAttribute() returns null when attribute has value

Tags: javascript, dom

The value of `elParentAttr` is `'level4'` the first time `traverseUp` is called but every time after is `null`. Why is this? Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/szj9emgr/).

JavaScript:

```
function traverseUp(el, attr) {
    var elParent = el.parentNode,
        elParentAttr = el.parentNode.getAttribute(attr);

    console.log(elParent);
    console.log(elParentAttr);

    traverseUp(elParent);
}

traverseUp((document.getElementsByClassName('level5'))[0], 'class');
```

Document:

```
<div class="level1">
    <div class="level2">
        <div class="level3">
            <div class="level4">
                <div class="level5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're calling it with the loop, aren't you missing the second parameter?

from `traverseUp(elParent);` to `traverseUp(elParent, attr);` ?

Comment: @maxhallinan No problem, don't forget the green tick :)